# Service behaviour in Entity - how to avoid service injection into entity?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dependency-injection, dns, domain-driven-design

I have an entity structure as follows:

```
IManager: IDeletable
{
IEnumerable<IFund> Funds {get;}
IFailureNotification Delete();
}

IFund : IDeletable
{
IEnumerable<IFundClass> FundClasses
IFailureNotification Delete();
}

IFundClass: IDeletable, IInvestable
{
IFailureNotification Delete();
}
```

And I have a service which takes an `IDeletable` and calls Delete on it. Depending on the return value it then either commits the transaction or rolls it back. I'm using NHibernate to persist the classes so can't put RI in the DB and catch the exception (which I wouldn't like anyway).

This is a classic case for polymorphism and the `Manager` loops through its `Funds` and deletes them before deleting itself, the `Fund` in turn delete the `FundClass`es before deleting themselves, so the service can just take any entity implementing `IDeletable` and know that the deletion will perform the appropriate actions at all levels.

Here's the problem: The fund classes need to find if they're being used in a completely separate context using the `IInvestable` interface which they don't know anything about. This requires a service - the `IInvestmentCalculationService`.

Obviously I don't want to inject the `InvestmentCalculationService` into the fund class entity constructor and I don't want to inject it into the delete method as this is on Funds and Managers as well as many other classes so doesn't make any sense - also means that as soon as we have more requirements we have to change the delete methods on everything.

I'm a bit tempted by the Domain Events model here: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/ but I'm not confident that it's right as I'm trying to get data back from the triggered event handler - which would work but smells a little bit wrong, and all the examples only show fire and forget situations.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for their help, I was really impressed by the audience I attracted! I especially liked mcintyre's philosophy and it's genuinely affected my thinking since. In this case though we went for double dispatch. Feels a little more stable.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

"Obviously I don't want to inject the `InvestmentCalculationService`".

Its the word 'obviously' that I don't like. I still haven't felt compelled by the results from googling "injecting services into entities". The top posts on the subject boil down to "it doesn't feel right and you can use domain events/double dispatch to do it anyway so don't do it".

I personally think it's fine to inject services into entities and reckon you should stop worrying about it and do it. Maybe don't inject the whole InvestmentCalculationService, but inject the BitsOfInvestmentCalculationServiceThatINeedToKnowAboutService if you feel the entity doesn't need to have access to the whole thing.

Domain events is no good in your situation unless you add a return value (which basically makes it into a dressed up service locator) and with double dispatch, the thing you are injecting has to come from somewhere higher up the call stack - probably an injected value to the entry point class which in all likeliness doesn't use that dependency.

Just inject the InvestmentCalculationService into the entity and get on with your life.

Comment: by 'Just inject the InvestmentCalculationService into the entity', do u mean, injecting via the constructor, OR as a parameter in the Delete method?

Comment: Use the constructor, if you put it on the delete method, the caller will need to have knowledge of the InvestmentCalculationService, which is breaking encapsulation.

Comment: follow up question, usually this would work ok, except for instance, when i load the entities from a database, if i have a thousand rows in the database, does that mean for these thousand records, i will then have to inject these dependencies to each and every entity, even if i do not need to call the delete method?, e.g. when i want to list all rows on a web page.

Comment: If you are loading 10000 records, the cost of the ctor parameters is going to be negligible. The cost will be in deserializing and hydrating the entities, which will involve many many other objects being created, used and discarded.

http://ayende.com/blog/3167/creating-objects-perf-implications

Comment: You can also inject a factory Func<InvestmentCalculationService> as opposed to InvestmentCalculationService  if you prefer, and creating the service is expensive for some reason.

Comment: thanx for the response, i think i will go with injecting the Func<InvestmentCalculationService>. however the second part of my question was that it was feeling 'not right' to inject a service even if i do not need to use it(not necessarily regarding performance), i.e., for my List action, i do not need that service, yet i will be forced to inject it. reason i mention this is that, normally, if the container does the wiring, i wouldnt care much about whether it is used or not, question arises when i have to manually added these dependancies each and every time.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we've done in situations like these is have the Delete not do the actual deletion, but instead use a collecting parameter for things to delete.  The Delete() method would register itself and any other objects, which then get replayed by another service.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, 

I'm not sure to how this solves the problem. How does the second deletion service know to check if a `FundClass` is invested? Does this not end up with if (x is IFundClass) then _fundClassChecker.check(x); ?

One possible solution that I thought of this morning is to inject in a `IDeletionValidationFactory` into the Delete method. Then the fund class can call `GetFundClassDeletionValidator` and use this check that it is OK for deletion.

This feels like a slightly abstracted version of double dispatch to me. What do you think of this?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

How about having an interface

```
public interface ICanBeDeleted<T>
{
    bool CanBeDeleted(T itemToBeDeleted);
}
```

Before actually deleting ask your container for all implementations of this interface, invoke the `CanBeDeleted` function and if any return false then do not delete.  Your `InvestmentCalculationService` would implement `ICanBeDeleted<FundClass>` and register with the container.